# Set Grid Mode as default for some specific categories - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have list mode view set as default for my whole store, however, some categories I would like to have grid view mode set as default.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

**Magento 2 doesn't support with Custom layout Update value for mode show grid and list same as 1 from directly setting xml code.**

You have to just create category level dropdown custom attribute inside admin panel.

Ex. If you have create attribute like `show_mode` with grid and list value.

After setting value for each category from admin and you have to check condition inside theme `list.phtml` file.

code for `list.phtml` file,

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');

//get current category showmode using regirstry
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    //check list value in db 1 or 0.
    //just for example. if listmode have set value 1 in db then showmode 1 otherwise grid mode
    if($category->getShowMode() == 1){ 
        $showGrid = 'list'; 
    }else{
        $showGrid = 'grid';
    }

?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($showGrid == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
                //echo '<pre>';print_r($_product->getData());
            ?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>

                        <div class="product-sku"> <?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?></div>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product);  ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()): ?>
                                        <a href="#"
                                           class="action towishlist"
                                           aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                           data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                           data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                           role="button">
                                            <span class="icon icon-like"></span>
                                            <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php
                                    $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
                                    ?>
                                    <a href="#"
                                       class="action tocompare"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                       role="button">
                                       <span class="icon icon-compare"></span>
                                        <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rakesh has already given the correct answer, let me add some more details to this answer. 
To show categories in a custom way, you need to create a new module and add an attribute considering it as show_mode name. Below is the code for the same:-
Firstly you need to add setup/installData.php in your module and add the install function which will create the attribute(Magento 2.1+ version):-

```
   <?php

namespace W3solver\Customcategorymode\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'show_mode', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Show Mode',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'source' => 'W3solver\Customcategorymode\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Showmode',
            'sort_order' => 102,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'Display Settings',
                ]
        );


        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

To view the show mode field in admin panel UI components needs to be created in view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="display_settings">
            <field name="show_mode">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">W3solver\Customcategorymode\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Showmode</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">102</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Show Mode</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>    
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

Also add a source model in Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Showmode.php and write below function:-

```
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList::VIEW_MODE_LIST, 'label' => __('List')],
                ['value' => \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList::VIEW_MODE_GRID, 'label' => __('Grid')],
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
```

Now you need to override list.phtml file in frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="W3solver_Customcategorymode::product/list.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you can continue with the suggestion as Rakesh has mentioned and change the list.phtml code.

```
 if($category->getShowMode() == 'list'){ 
        $showGrid = 'list'; 
    }else{
        $showGrid = 'grid';
    }

if ($showGrid == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.You can find it here, i have added the code(http://www.w3solver.com/code-to-show-different-mode-list-or-grid-mode-for-different-category/)

Comment: this will throw error on search result page, because category registry will be empty on search result page.