Magneto 2.4 | Display specific categories in list mode rather than grid
Is there a way to display specific categories on list mode rather than the usuall grid mode. A few categories of mine would need that due to the product standards and the used short_description within them.
Layout XML Updates arent possible since they got removed.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115375/set-grid-mode-as-default-for-some-specific-categories-magento-2
Please check the above link.
